# qual forma destrutivas e não destrutivas para obter o último elemento de um array?

Tags: php, array

Surgiu essa pergunta em um grupo, porém não souberam de tal informação, vocês saberiam a resposta?

Answer (score 2):

̶U̶m̶a̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶m̶a̶ ̶*̶d̶e̶s̶t̶r̶u̶t̶i̶v̶a̶*̶ ̶d̶e̶ ̶o̶b̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶o̶ ̶u̶l̶t̶i̶m̶o̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶d̶e̶ ̶u̶m̶ ̶a̶r̶r̶a̶y̶ ̶é̶ ̶u̶t̶i̶l̶i̶z̶a̶n̶d̶o̶ ̶a̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶ç̶ã̶o̶ ̶`̶a̶r̶r̶a̶y̶_̶p̶o̶p̶(̶)̶`̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶ ̶e̶x̶t̶r̶a̶i̶ ̶u̶m̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶a̶l̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶a̶r̶r̶a̶y̶ ̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶t̶o̶r̶n̶a̶ ̶o̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶e̶x̶t̶r̶a̶i̶d̶o̶ ̶o̶u̶ ̶`̶N̶U̶L̶L̶`̶ ̶c̶a̶s̶o̶ ̶o̶ ̶a̶r̶r̶a̶y̶ ̶s̶e̶j̶a̶ ̶v̶a̶z̶i̶o̶:̶
̶

```
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶<̶?̶p̶h̶p̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶$̶a̶r̶r̶ ̶=̶ ̶[̶'̶S̶e̶g̶u̶n̶d̶a̶'̶,̶ ̶'̶T̶e̶r̶ç̶a̶'̶,̶ ̶'̶Q̶u̶a̶r̶t̶a̶'̶,̶ ̶'̶Q̶u̶i̶n̶t̶a̶'̶,̶ ̶'̶S̶e̶x̶t̶a̶'̶]̶;̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶$̶u̶l̶t̶i̶m̶o̶ ̶=̶ ̶a̶r̶r̶a̶y̶_̶p̶o̶p̶(̶$̶a̶r̶r̶)̶;̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶p̶r̶i̶n̶t̶_̶r̶(̶$̶a̶r̶r̶)̶;̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶p̶r̶i̶n̶t̶_̶r̶(̶$̶u̶l̶t̶i̶m̶o̶)̶;̶
̶
```

̶R̶e̶t̶o̶r̶n̶a̶n̶d̶o̶:̶
̶

```
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶A̶r̶r̶a̶y̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶(̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶[̶0̶]̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶S̶e̶g̶u̶n̶d̶a̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶[̶1̶]̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶T̶e̶r̶ç̶a̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶[̶2̶]̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶Q̶u̶a̶r̶t̶a̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶[̶3̶]̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶Q̶u̶i̶n̶t̶a̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶)̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶S̶e̶x̶t̶a̶
̶
```

Uma forma não destrutiva de obter o último elemento de um array é manipulado seu índice através da função [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php) que retorna o número de elementos:

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$arr[1] = "índice 1";
$arr[2] = "índice 2";
$arr[0] = "índice 0";
print_r($arr[count($arr) - 1]);
```

Que retorna:

```
índice 2
```

**Consideração sobre a função [`end()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.end.php).**

A função `end()` é utilizada para obter de forma não destrutiva o **último elemento adicionado a um array**, porém que fique claro que **essa função não irá retornar o elemento de maior índice em arrays cujo os índices sejam numéricos** sempre retornando o último elemento adicionado, exemplo:

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$arr[1] = "índice 1";
$arr[2] = "índice 2";
$arr[0] = "índice 0";
print_r(end($a));
```

Retornando:

```
índice 0
```

**Consideração sobre a função [`array_pop()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-pop.php).**

Uma forma *destrutiva* de obter o **último elemento adicionado** a um array. **Essa função não irá retornar e remover o elemento de maior índice em arrays cujo os índices sejam numéricos** sempre retornando e removendo o último elemento adicionado, exemplo:

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$arr[1] = "índice 1";
$arr[2] = "índice 2";
$arr[0] = "índice 0";
print_r(array_pop($arr));
```

Retornando e removendo:

```
índice 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A forma não-destrutiva é o [`end`](https://php.net/end) citado pelo colega da outra resposta, ou acesso direto pelo último índice, se for uma array indexada numericamente – se não for, não faz sentido falar em "último". A forma destrutiva é o [`array_splice`](https://php.net/array_splice).

Exemplo:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4];
$ultimo = end($arr);
var_dump($ultimo);
var_dump($arr);
$ultimo = array_splice($arr, -1, 1);
var_dump($ultimo[0]);
var_dump($arr);
```

[Veja funcionando no ideone](https://ideone.com/wWj15W).

Answer (score -1):

Em php basta usar o método `end()` e ele retorna o ultimo elemento do array.
Leia a documentação para mais informações:
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.end.php